# how to add var's to a .append string

Tags: jquery, xml

I am parsing some xml

```
<item>
    <title>New Story Test</title>
    <description>Story 1</description>
    <link>http://www.dirtybirddesignlab.com/tour</link>
    <pubDate>Tue, 9 Nov 2010 09:32:16 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
```

and need the output to be as such

```
<link><title></link> | <description>
```

but no luck with the following, its only displaying the "link" and there is no href applied

```
$(xml).find('item').each(function() {
    var title = $(this).find('title').text();
    var page  = $(this).find('link').text();
    var desc  = $(this).find('description').text();
    $('#ticker').append($('<li>', {text: page}, {text: title}, {text: desc}));
});
$('#ticker').newsTicker();
```

Comment: which part of your code applies the `href`? I don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#ticker').append($('<li>', {
   text: page + title + desc
}));
```

should do it. To separate them you might want to call:

```
$('#ticker').append($('<li>', {
   text: [page, title, desc].join(' / ')
}));
```

Comment: wow there's a million ways to skin a cat huh? I beat it into submission and got this to work..is it ok? $('#ticker').append($('<li><a href="' + page + '">' + title + '</a>' + '&nbsp;' + '-' + '&nbsp;' + desc + '</li>'));